# Hide scrollbar for one element but not others (on click/event)

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrollbar, scrollbars

I'm building an interface where there is a slide-out editor on the right side of the screen. It is possible that the content on both the page AND in the editor requires scrolling, in which case, there is an unsightly double scroll bar.

What I'm trying to do is set the visibility of the PAGE scroll bar to hidden when the editor is invoked, but keep the visibility for the scroll bar in the editor.

**Important Note:** When the editor is open, I still want the page content to be scrollable underneath...so `overflow:hidden` on the page is not an option.

Relevant code below. [**Here's a Fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TGX5D/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<button>Open Editor</button>
<div class="editor">Editor line 1
    <br/>Editor line 2
    ...
</div>
<div class="content">This is line 1 
    <br/>This is line 2
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 14px;
    height: 18px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 6px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.noScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(".content").toggleClass("noScroll");
        $(".editor").toggle("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: When you pop out the sidebar, use jQuery to give body the CSS property overflow:hidden;

Comment: That works, but I want the page below the editor to remain scrollable. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want the content still to be scrollable, but you don't want the scroll bar to appear right next to the scroll bar for the editor? I would do this by putting all the content except the editor in a div with width and height of 100%. Then I'd change the width to 100%-<editor width> when the editor is open. That way the scroll bar for the editor will be on the far right and the scroll bar for the content will be on the left of the editor and the right of the content.

Comment: Or perhaps you can change body to overflow:hidden when you're hovering over the editor, but editor to overflow:hidden when you aren't hovering over the editor.

Comment: The latter sounds plausible. I'll experiment with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from what is mentioned by Qaz in the comments, following modification can also be done in the css to get the desired effect:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:2em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
body:hover {
    overflow:auto;
}
.editor:hover {
    overflow:auto;
}
.editor {
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    background:#eee;
    padding:20px;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TGX5D/5/

Check if it works for you.

Comment: This seems to work. Ideally I'd be able to see the scrollbar on the editor without needing to hover over it, but this can be an interim solution. Thank you!

Comment: For that, you can remove overflow:hidden from .editor css and set it to overflow:auto. And remove the hover effect from editor css.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I think I actually prefer your first version on hover. I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use:

```
 body{
 overflow:hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

in css, and call it when you pull out the side bar

Comment: That works, but I want the page below the editor to remain scrollable. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to still be scrolling for me, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/TGX5D/3/. When I open the editor, the scrollbar goes away for the page content, but I can't scroll. I want to still be able to scroll both the page content AND the editor content.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Sorry about that. To do that you would just have to add this